# request mapping with special char for attributes similar to google maps

Tags: java, spring-boot, web, getmethod

I am using Spring boot and I want to pass two double values in a manner similar to Google maps: 
instead of having **/api?x=1.1&y=2.2** and get the request parameters I want to do: **/api/@1.1,2.2**

At the level of the controller, how can I get those two parameters from the second get request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@GetMapping("/api/@{term:.+}")
public void index(@PathVariable String term) {
    // term is whatever after the "@"
    // you can parse the term to what you want
    // {term:.+} is a regex mapping for including the last dot
}
```

e.g.
If you request **../api/@1.1,2.2**
Term will be "1.1,2.2".
Split the term by "," and convert the strings to doubles.